# Dijkstra's algorithm does not work?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

I mean Dijkstra's algorithm for the shortest path.

Sorry for noob question.

In all descriptions that I saw (including wikipedia), on every step, it always selects the nearest neighbor based on examining their weights.

Imagine that we have following paths from source $A$ to destination $B$
(I will list weights of different paths, not full graph - for brevity):

1. $19 \to 2 \to 2 \to 10$
2. $5 \to 10 \to 10 \to 10 \to 5$
3. $2 \to 15 \to 15 \to 10 \to 2$

If Dijkstra always select the neighbor with smallest weight,
it will always go for 3. - although it leads to the heaviest path!

Where am I wrong?
Does anybody have a 'working' pseudo-code for Dijkstra algorithm?

Thanks.

Comment: 19 comes before 2+15+15.

Answer (score 3):

The point of Dijkstra's is that it is not greedy like some others, sure it will look at the node after the first edge of 3 first. But then it will look at 2, and then the next vertex on 2, updating shortest paths as it goes. Eventually the 19 to start 1 off will be the next best choice, and then from there it will find the nice 2's and it will catch up along 1 so to speak.

It would help to see the graph to give you a better idea what's going on. Working pseudocode is on the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm).